# Why does transforming a Dask Series to categorical slow down computation?

Tags: pandas, dask

I have ~5.5GB dataset stored in Parquet. I have a series in that dataset `account_language` which is initially of type object (string).

Can anyone explain why it takes much longer to do the same calculation AFTER converting the series to a categorical? Am I converting to categorical incorrectly?

```
df = dd.read_parquet('dataset', engine='fastparquet')

%time pre_cat_val_counts = df.account_language.value_counts().compute()
```

> CPU times: user 2.9 s, sys: 678 ms, total: 3.57 s Wall time: 3.34 s

```
df = df.categorize(columns=['account_language'])
%time post_cat_val_counts = df.account_language.value_counts().compute()
```

> CPU times: user 1min 4s, sys: 23 s, total: 1min 27s >Wall time: 1min 9s

Answer (score 2):

So in the process of thinking this through I worked it out, but thought as I'd written the question up I may as well leave something in case it's useful. The cause was a misunderstanding on my part of how Dask functions.

The issue was that calling `.compute()` was actually running the process of both the categorisation transformation, and the value_count operation together. I had essentially queued up the intensive process of categorising, and the `.value_count()` command and was measuring the time it took to do both. Running `.compute()` on the categorisation FIRST then made the later calculations much faster.

```
df = df.categorize(columns=['account_language']).compute()
%time post_cat_val_counts = df.account_language.value_counts()
```

> CPU times: user 42.5 ms, sys: 1.08 ms, total: 43.6 ms
>   Wall time: 42.4 ms